# Which method for handling conditions inside a function would be the most practical?

Tags: function, benchmarking

What's fastest, safest, and most practical way of handling conditions inside a function where a condition match must be passed before the function can proceed with any code at all? Below I have a function that returns on condition failure, and another function that only checks for the condition success:

```
function x()
{
    if ( !condition ) return;

    [code]
}
```

Or

```
function y()
{
    if ( condition )
    {
        [code]
    }
}
```

Comment: What makes you think that (a) it matters or that (b) one will be faster than the other ?

Comment: I personally prefer the second method. Unless, of course, your `if` statements are getting too deeply nested. Then use the first way or `continue` if your language supports it. And it really depends on the specific code.

Comment: Speed won't make a big enough impact to matter, both are equally safe, both are basically equally practical. It all comes down to personal preference, I prefer the first.

Comment: This is really about personal preference and readability rather than performance. I normally use `b` as I prefer just one return statement, however if you have allot of code in the else block then `a` would be more readable

Answer (score 0):

[McCabe's cyclomatic complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) punishes functions with more than one return statement. I guess to provide a formalism that supports [structured programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_programming) (one entry point for each function/["Goto Statement Considered Harmful"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_To_Statement_Considered_Harmful#Criticism_and_decline)) taken to the extreme, i.e. one exit point for each function.

Reducing the number of return statements in a function reduces the number of break-points to insert in a debugging situation where the final values of function local variables are to be inspected.

If your development method involves frequent use of a debugger you could argue for using the `y()` approach.

Comment: I'd argue that `x` is better for debugging (as long as you separate that into 2 separate lines) because it's an **initial** check, you're *very* unlikely to want to evaluate final values of variables. I've encountered many scenario's where `x`'s structure helps and none where `y`'s structure helps (yes, none).